# Why Rust Return Type Infer Diffent With IDE?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

```
use futures_util::{FutureExt, StreamExt};
use warp::{Filter, filters::BoxedFilter, Reply};

// websocket echo
pub fn websocket_filter() -> BoxedFilter<(impl Reply, )> {
    return warp::path!("echo")
        .and(warp::ws())
        .map(|ws: warp::ws::Ws| {
            ws.on_upgrade(|websocket| {
                // Just echo all messages back...
                let (tx, rx) = websocket.split();
                rx.forward(tx).map(|result| {
                    if let Err(e) = result {
                        eprintln!("websocket error: {:?}", e);
                    }
                })
            });

            "end"
        }).boxed();
}
```

With code above, Idea show error message 'mismatched types [E0308]expected `BoxedFilter<(impl Reply,)>`, found `BoxFuture<&str>`'.
But it built success.

Comment: Intellij is notorious for partially reimplementing languages in their IDEs. I think rust is not an exception and, in this case, their inference logic is different from that of the actual compiler.

Comment: Is there anyway can I solve or ignore this error?

Comment: You should report it as a bug in your IDE.

Comment: Ok,I will try it.